# How do I save the model and modelDetail with SharedPreferences in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class User{
String userName;
DateTime userDate;
List<UserDetail> detail;
}
class UserDetail{
String adress;
bool isActive;
DateTime dateTime
}
```

like this ? 
How can I save with SharedPreferences ?

Answer (score 0):

Shared prefrences is used like a `Map<String,String>` (if I recall currectly).
So the way I'd do it is by implementing toJson and FromJson for your model, converting the `Map` from the toJson() to string, and storing it with some key thay you'll be able to access later. when retrieving the data, use the fromJson method with decoding of the string retrieved and you'll have a new object with the same values.

Edit:
best way to convertto and from json is by using code generation:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: All the info you need is in the link I attached, once you have the data as a json you can turn it to a string (there are stackoverflow questions that were answered already for that) and also questions for how to save and retrieve data using the shared preferences. Good luck!